# Problem with subscribing to robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot, odom-combined, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with Turtlebot. I launched the following launch files containing openni, minimal.launch, depthimage_to_laserscan and robot_pose_ekf

On the workstation, When I run the command rostopic list I can see both /odom and /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined in the list of topics.

Even when I run rostopic echo /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined I can see the content of the that topic on the terminal.

Now, the problem when I subscribe to this topic in my C++ file like this

robot.OdomCombinedSubscriber = nh.subscribe<nav_msgs::Odometry>("/robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined", 10,  &TurtlebotRobot::OdometryCombinedCallback, &robot);

There is nothing received in the callback.
When this instruction is executed, there is a error message in red in the Tutrlebot saying:

**[ERROR] [1389688193.050254972]: Client [/testApp] wants topic /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined to have datatype/md5sum [nav_msgs/Odometry/cd5e73d190d741a2f92e81eda573aca7], but our version has [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped/953b798c0f514ff060a53a3498ce6246]. Dropping connection.**

I got a similar error for the bumper message but this was when I was using Groovy on turtlebot and Hydro on workstation. Now, I put both to hydro but still I got the message above.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117541/problem-with-subscribing-to-robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined/) by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2014-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just found the error. It is in here

```
robot.OdomCombinedSubscriber = nh.subscribe<nav_msgs::odometry>("/robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined", 10, &TurtlebotRobot::OdometryCombinedCallback, &robot);
```

The message type should be `geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped` and not `nav_msgs::odometry`

I changed instruction to

```
robot.OdomCombinedSubscriber = nh.subscribe<geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped>("/robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined", 10,  &TurtlebotRobot::OdometryCombinedCallback, &robot);
```

and it worked!

---

Originally posted by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) with karma: 253 on 2014-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2